# What is best way to get rid of LazyInitializationException on calculated fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, lazy-initialization

Hi I'm fairly new to Hibernate and im getting LazyInitiationException. Please if you can give me an example on how to solve this. I have calculated dervied field and I'm adding @transient on it but doesn't seem to be working. Can you please tell me how to use it and pass this in Jsf.

Also if DTO is the way to go. Can you give me an example of how to do DTO because this is not something i can get from db and create a view. Any help would be appreciated?

This is my jsf:

```
<pe:dynaFormControl type="EMPLOYEE_VALUE" for="employeeDyna#{tab.id}-#{subtab.id}">
        <p:autoComplete id="employeeDyna#{tab.id}-#{subtab.id}" scrollHeight="250" value="#{data.entityValue.employee}" converter="#{entityConverter}" completeMethod="#{autoCompletionBean.employeeAutoCompleteList}"
            var="emp" itemLabel="#{emp.getFullName()}" itemValue="#{emp}" maxResults="500" dropdown="true" forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="2" queryDelay="800" required="#{data.cf.derived}" requiredMessage="#{secondEmployeeBean.getRequiredMessage(data.cf.name)}"
            disabled="#{empty bean_Data.selectedAccount and !PARAM_OPTIONAL}">
            <f:attribute name="selectedAccount" value="#{bean_Data.selectedAccount}" />
        </p:autoComplete>
    </pe:dynaFormControl>
```

This is my entity class:

```
import java.beans.Transient;    

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee extends AbstractIdentity {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_TYPE_CODE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Getter
    private EEntityType companyTypeCode;


    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "COMPANY_TYPE_CODE"))
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "long",
    metaValues = {
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = CLass1.class, value = EEntityType.CLass1_CODE),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = CLass2.class, value = EEntityType.CLass2_CODE),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = CLass3.class, value = EEntityType.CLass3_CODE),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = CLass4.class, value = EEntityType.CLass4_CODE),
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    @BatchSize(size = AppConfig.BATCH_SIZE)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private AbstractCompany entityCompany;

    @Transient
     public String getFullName(boolean withCompany) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(getName());

        if (withCompany) {

            if (null != getEntityCompany() && !getEntityCompany().getName().trim().equals("")) {
                stringBuffer.append(" - ");
                stringBuffer.append(getEntityCompany().getName());
            }
        }

        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

}
```

This is the error:

```
javax.el.ELException: /includes/components/customFieldEditView.xhtml @76,70 itemLabel="#{emp.getFullName()}": org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.getItemLabel(AutoComplete.java:162)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeInput(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:212)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSingleMarkup(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:154)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeMarkup(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:137)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaFormRenderer.encodeBody(DynaFormRenderer.java:283)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaFormRenderer.encodeMarkup(DynaFormRenderer.java:115)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.dynaform.DynaFormRenderer.encodeEnd(DynaFormRenderer.java:80)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:196)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:151)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:104)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:65)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:37)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:143)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at org.springframework.faces.support.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:87)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:293)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.doEnter(ViewState.java:185)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:527)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.start(RequestControlContextImpl.java:234)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.SubflowState.doEnter(SubflowState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:552)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:231)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.abc.web.filter.abcWebAppFilter.doFilter(abcWebAppFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:164)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:79)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 182 more
```

Answer (score 1):

My question is: what's the relationship of your `Employee` entity and your `AbstractCompany`? Being a single-valued object (not collection type), I'd assume that it could either be one-to-one or many-to-one.

Judging by the stacktrace, you have lazy-loading problem. By default, Hibernate performs lazy loading regardless of association mapping.

> By default, Hibernate uses lazy select fetching for collections and
>   lazy proxy fetching for single-valued associations. These defaults
>   make sense for most associations in the majority of applications.

I think the problem in your code is this:
`getEntityCompany().getName()` inside your `getFullName` method. You tried to access a property of a lazily-loaded entity (`AbstractCompany`). You cannot do this once you are outside of a Hibernate session/transaction.

You have 2 options:

**1) EAGER load the relationship**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private AbstractCompany entityCompany;
```

or if you use one-to-one (that's why I asked first what's the relationship type between the Employee and AbstractCompany)

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private AbstractCompany entityCompany;
```

**2) Load the relationship while inside the Hibernate session**

```
Hibernate.initialize(employee.getEntityCompany());
```

Comment: Sorry i missed some code. Please take a look at updated one.

Comment: Try to add this to your `@Any` annotation `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`

Comment: Are there any other solutions than `EAGER`? not sure if i would like to use Eager as it might affect performance.

Comment: Then you're left with option 2 or you can follow the suggestion from the other answer - building a facade.

Comment: I just don't know how to build a facade. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because you are trying to load fields outside of the transaction which was used to retrieve your data.

When hibernate retrieve data it will create proxy entities for the fields. When first access one of these proxies hibernate will send a new request to get this specific piece of data. The problem is that hibernate cannot do this once the transaction is closed.

You need to either make sure your database request load the fields you are interested in as well (eager annotation or join in the query) or you need to retrieve this data beforehand (accessing it inside the transaction or initialize the proxies, still in the transaction).

Since you're sending this data to a view I recommend using a facade. 
The facade will contain all data your page needs to get built. So in your service, where you have your transaction, transform your results into a facade your page will be able to use.

A facade is pretty much only a POJO to store data for your view.

Comment: Ah. Can you give me an example of a facade and how to invoke it in UI?

Comment: As I said a facade is a POJO i.e. just members and getter setters.  And you pass the facade to your view in the exact same way you do your entity. Actually you use your facade exactly as you use your entity. the only difference is that you are abstracting the entity in relation to the view.